# Overwrite the mosaic raster generated using gdal_merge.py?

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-merge

Is it possible to overwrite the raster generated using gdal_merge.py? When I ran the command:

```
% gdal_merge.py -init 255 -o out.tif in1.tif in2.tif
```

it works fine, but if I ran the same command and out.tif was already previously generated, it overwrites out.tif to a uniform raster (i.e., all values equal to 255).

Comment: What do mean by "to a wrong raster"?

Comment: @user30184 I have updated the question to explain what I mean by wrong raster, thanks!

Comment: By reading the documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html your command looks right.

Comment: The command is correct, the issue is on the overwriting, or running the command twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old question, but for completeness here is an answer. You can't pass in an overwrite flag to gdal_merge.py as you can some other gdal functions. One workaround is to delete the file (if it exists) before you run gdal_merge.py:

```
import os
try:
    os.remove('path_to_file')
except OSError:
    pass
```